# Has 'dreich' surreptitiously crossed the pond and does it lurk, somewhere, in AmE?

Tags: etymology, american-english, scottish-english

The word *dreich* has only made one appearance on EL&U, that I can find, and it was a questionably brief appearance in answer to a [single word request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254220/what-do-you-call-it-when-its-not-raining-but-the-atmosphere-causes-everything/254247#254247).

This unassuming word did, however, top the polls five years ago in a [Scotsman survey](https://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/dreich-tops-poll-of-favourite-scots-words-1-2754328) to find the most favoured word in the Scots language by its own speakers.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dreich), at least online, has a minimal note on *dreich* which states only 'dreary' and misses the breadth of the word in its spoken usage.

Born in the far north of Scotland in the early 1950s, not far from where the last wolf was killed in Britain and almost within sight of the ruins of a Pictish *broch*, I learned the word almost as soon as I was able to drink my free school milk unaided, for the weather in that area (one hundred miles north of Inverness) is almost always *dreich.*

As the saying goes in those parts, 'if you can see the hills it is about to rain and if you cannot see them it is raining already'.

The EL&U answer which quoted *dreich* was accurate in comment :

> Your dictionaries, Martha, are inaccurate. The word *dreich* explicity implies humidity and dampness. It would never be used to describe dry conditions.

This agrees with my own usage (and the usage in the north of Scotland) to describe dark overshadowing clouds, persistent (though never copious) drizzle and a cold (though not frozen) wind.

It is such a suitable word for Scottish weather that I am surprised it has no foothold in other parts and I am convinced that it must have crossed the Atlantic - in the Mayflower or later - to lurk, perhaps little noticed, in some dreary location where it is whispered over mugs of steaming cocoa as the cold dampness knocks quietly at the door.

Is there any sign of it, in any shape or form, in AmE ?

Comment: So the question is: “is dreich used in AmE”?

Comment: You’re more apt to see it spelt *dree* as in *to dree the drither*: *“He did great pyne and meikle sorrow dree.”* Wait wait, that’s still Scottish! :)

Comment: @user159691 Or - has it modified into something else ? Question edited to include this.

Comment: @user159691 It isn't slang in Scotland as the Scotsman survey indicates.

Comment: I guess they refer to its usage in England.

Comment: With some exceptions, Scottish immigrants primarily settled in areas where the weather was decidedly not dreich, like Virginia, South Carolina, and the Mountain South. If anywhere, it would have survived in New England, but I seriously doubt it did.

Comment: The only hits I found on COHA are from [this novel, *I'll Take Manhattan* by Judith Krantz](https://books.google.com/books?id=hjpvZ9kvOXoC&pg=PA218&dq=Francisco.+Come+on,+stop+stalling.+%22+%22+Basically,+it+was+the+dreich.+%22+%22+Of+course+it+was,+%22+India+said+soothingly.+%22+What&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG34GZkerYAhVMHqwKHd6vCNcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Francisco.%20Come%20on%2C%20stop%20stalling.%20%22%20%22%20Basically%2C%20it%20was%20the%20dreich.%20%22%20%22%20Of%20course%20it%20was%2C%20%22%20India%20said%20soothingly.%20%22%20What&f=false), and it does seem to involve Scottish characters.

Comment: @KarlG Perhaps they were taking maximum advantage of the opportunity to escape _dreich_ weather for once in their lives.

Comment: As near as I can tell, they followed the tobacco trade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A search on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dreich%3Aeng_us_2012%2C%20dreich%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdreich%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreich%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdreich%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreich%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) show a few  usages of “***dreich***” in AmE, but they all appear to be related to Scots authors or to Scotland.

[The Dictionary of Contemporary Slang by Tony Thorne](https://books.google.it/books?id=3_6oRAJSHP4C&pg=PT343&lpg=PT343&dq=dreich%20usage&source=bl&ots=l-cwgYJo38&sig=MzgztQ5Ti1uCuMWDHRmjrrv8lJc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiryu_XjurYAhUMbxQKHWSNClQ4ChDoATABegQIExAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that “dreich” was used in England in the late ‘90s as a slang term.

> A dialect term which was occasionally heard as a colourful new colloquialism in self-conscious use amongst middle-class inhabitants of England in the late 1990s.
>
> - The weather is rather, as they say, dreich.

while the  [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=dreich) has no entry for “dreich”.

The [Dictionary of the Scots Language](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/dreich) entry for ***dreich*** suggest  that its usage is in Scotland and in north England dialect.

> (2) Of the weather, scenery, etc.: dreary, cheerless, bleak. Gen.Sc. Also in n.Eng. dial.
>
> Bnff. 1856  J. Collie Poems 120: 
>   Ae night when I came, wet and weary, Throu Habbie's howe baith drigh and dreary.
>
> Ags. 1924  A. Gray Any Man's Life 44: 
>   In the cauld dreich days when it's nicht on the back o' four.
>
> Fif. 1841  C. Gray Lays and Lyrics 83: 
>   The cauld frost had locked up ilk riv'let and fountain, As I took the dreich road that leads north to Dundee.
>
> Ayr. 1788  Burns Duncan Davison i.: 
>   The moor was dreigh, and Meg was skeigh, Her favour Duncan could na win.
>
> Kcb. 1881  T. Newbigging Poems 56: 
>   He's owre the hills that I love best, Yon lonely hills so dark and dree.
>
> Rxb. 1916  Kelso Chron. (31 March) 4/1: 
>   Doon ablow it's dreich and gloomy as we wade among the slush.

Evidence suggests that the term didn’t survive in its original spelling  in AmE though it most likely crossed the Atlantic.

As suggested by @tchrist in a comment the related term [dree](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dree) can be found in AmE, but its usage is [not common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dree%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cdree%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdree%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdree%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0). Other variants are dreigh and  driegh.

Comment: All interesting stuff. Thank you. Up-voted and accepted.